# We draw $3 $cards without replacement from a standard $52$-card deck. Find the probability of drawing exactly $2$ kings?

Tags: probability

Help with probability when drawing $3$ cards without replacement from a standard deck

Comment: To help us to help you, it would be good to tell us what you tried, what you don't understand, and so on.

Comment: I believe I am on the right path, but I am pretty sure my answer needs to be multiplied by the # of ways two kings can be drawn?? {(4/52)•(3/51)•(48/50)} • 3????

Answer (score 3):

Use the Hypergeometric Distribution:

$\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{3}}$ $=$ $\dfrac{{6} \cdot {48}}{22,100}$ $= 0.013$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A) = 3\cdot \dfrac{48}{52}\cdot \dfrac{4}{51}\cdot \dfrac{3}{50}$